# Synchronized Multi-Value Columns in SharePoint

Tags: list, custom

I have a need to create a SharePoint list containing two or more synchronized, multi-value columns.  For example, let's say that I have a list of medicines and want to specify all of the active and inactive ingredients, along with their corresponding strengths.  The data should look something like the following:

```
 Product Column:  Product X
 Ingredient Name Column:  Ingredient 1, Ingredient 2, Ingredient 3
 Ingredient Strength Column: 5mg, 10mg, 20mg
 Ingredient Type Column: Active, Inactive, Inactive
```

Essentially, I am trying to capture that fact that Product X contains the following 3 ingredients:

```
 Ingredient 1 / 5mg / Active
 Ingredient 2 / 10mg / Inactive
 Ingredient 3 / 20mg / Inactive
```

I would like to create three multi-value columns (Name, Strength and Type), but enable the user to specify values in a synchronized way.  This would ensure that the first value in each of the three multi-value columns pertain to the same product.   The same would hold true for subsequent ingredients.

Does anyone know how I can do this in SharePoint?  Any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a list named **Ingredientes** with three columns

   - Name
   - Strength
   - Type
2. Create a second list named **Products** with at least two columns

   - Name
   - Ingredients (a lookup column referencing first list, allowing multiple values)

More info: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)